# How to determine the maximum number of cache misses that occur through the virtual to physical address translation?

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture, virtual-memory, cpu-cache

The following question reads:
Suppose that a CPU issues a read for an instruction and that read does not cause a page fault to be generated. Assuming that the MMU uses a TLB to do the address translation and that there is a single page table, what is the maximum number of cache misses that can occur throughout the entire process of translating the virtual address to a physical address and retrieving the instruction? (Assume, that there is only a level-1 cache for the DRAM.)

I do understand that the TLB is used to reduce the huge consequential cost of fetching from memory, but I don't understand virtual memory enough to be able to answer this question -I'm also aware that that TLB misses are rare. Anyways, I'd appreciate it if anyone can help me understand this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I mean if you want a worst case scenario on a platform with 4-level page tables, I guess it's something like 10 for a split load that crosses two pages, which is 1 + 1 + 4 + 4. That's 1 for the actual load of each of the two cache lines the load touches, and 4 for each level of the page table the CPU has to walk, times 2 walks since two pages are touched.

You can also look into the page table structure - perhaps there are scenarios where you can get more than once miss per level, e.g., if the paging structures themselves are allowed to be misaligned, or if there is any kind of search involved in the translation (rather than a direct lookup). There are probably other reasons you could suffer even more cache misses.

It would very hard to actually organize a situation where you suffered that many misses, since even if you totally defeat the TLBs, the higher level PTEs may appear in some level of the cache, or the CPU itself may cache them internally (in a non-architectural cache).

Answer (score 0):

The TLB caches page table entries.  A TLB miss means that a translation has to be looked up in the page table.

The CPU has the physical address of the top-level page table, so no more translations are required.  (That would lead to a chicken-and-egg problem).

However, assuming that the page-walk hardware (or software TLB-miss handler) accesses the page table through the cache hierarchy (which is the case in modern x86 CPUs, for example), each of the accesses required to find the right PTE can miss in the data cache.

Page tables are usually multi-level data structures, e.g. 3 or 4 levels deep on x86.

Note that real CPU designs may cache page-directory entries inside the TLB-miss handling hardware, separately from the data caches.